# Maximize Window to Have Client Area Just Fill Screen Issue (Windows 10, Win32 DLL)

Tags: winapi, bitmap, fullscreen, stretch, maximize-window

First, if this isn't a great way to do this, PLEASE suggest better.  I can't seem to find an exact solution to what must be a common desire (see post title).
My approach was to trap the WM_PAINT message and check whether the window position is maximized.  If it is, then run this code:

```
SetWindowLong(hCDGWnd, GWL_STYLE, 0); // remove all styling
SetWindowPos(hCDGWnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 1280, 720, SWP_SHOWWINDOW); // full screen is 1280 x 720
StretchDIBits(hdc, 0, 0, 1280, 720, CDG_XOFFSET, CDG_YOFFSET, CDG_RENDER_WIDTH, CDG_RENDER_HEIGHT,
              bmBits, (LPBITMAPINFO)&bmInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS, SRCCOPY);
```

What I want to see is my BITMAP stretched to fill the entire client area, which should just fill the entire screen.  Actually it is a section taken out of a larger bitmap.  It seems like the window is in fact full screen, but the bitmap is its normal size and not stretched.  Curiously, when I was fiddling with the window positioning stuff I had all kinds of attempts leaving the styling but trying to position the title bar and frame offscreen (see below) - the bitmap was appearing stretched just fine during those close but failed attempts.  Now I've got the window right, suddenly the bitmap no longer stretches.  Is there something about removing the styling that would screw up the StretchDIBits function?

Also, when I attempt leaving the style in place, and use AdjustWindowRect() to have my client size be fullscreen, it returns {-3, -26, 1283, 723 } which makes sense - 3 pixel border plus 23 more for title bar on top.  But, just to explore things, when I don't even test for maximized state, and just make the window have x = -3, y = -26, cx = 1286, cy = 749, then almost everything is fine except the bottom of the window is shy of fullscreen by about 4 pixels.  When I make the window height much bigger - say 760 - IT STAYS THE SAME HEIGHT!?  I so confused.  If try this maneuver only when maximized, it seems like windows ignores my attempts to have the title bar off the top of the screen.

Comment: It's better to [Extend Window Frame Using DWM to the entire window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe) and draw in the Extended Window Frame.

Comment: I did some research and it seems like Vista or later  is required for DWM.  I am writing a plugin that would definitely be considered retro.  I think a lot of end users might still be using old setups like XP cause if it ain't broke.  Also, DWM feels like overkill for what (seems to me) has to have been done in Windows since version 3.x.

Comment: Does [Full Screen Display and Implementing Drag to Move Dialogs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/december/c-q-a-full-screen-display-and-implementing-drag-to-move-dialogs) work for you? Using [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) to full screen display.